# App Engine and API accessing contacts

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I have created and running an app on Google App Engine. The app has several users who log in as themself but need to use a common set of CONTACTS. ie on just one user.

When retrieving contacts how do I set the USER NAME for the set of contacts to be retrieved.

At present it always looks at the list of contacts of the user who is logged in.

I am using:

```
    gd_client = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService()
    gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(gd_client)
    query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
    query.max_results = 10000
    feed=gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri()) 
    for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
```

I have the tokens stored for all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way, the user needs to grant access to your application to view the contacts in a process called OAuth2.
There is good tutorial on this [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

Comment: Also see http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide.html#Auth for calling Contact API v3 with OAuth 2.0